# Supergo ABCPdf8 Error: Html Render is blank?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, abcpdf

Heloo ,

I am stuck in this error while generating Pdf from HTML using ABCPdf8
my code is

```
    Dim PdfDocument As New WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc()
    Dim PdfId As Integer

    PdfDocument.Page = PdfDocument.AddPage()
    PdfId = PdfDocument.AddImageHtml(HTML)  // Crash over here
    PdfDocument.Transform.Translate(0, -10)

    While True
        If Not PdfDocument.Chainable(PdfId) Then
            Exit While
        End If
        PdfDocument.Page = PdfDocument.AddPage()
        PdfId = PdfDocument.AddImageToChain(PdfId)
    End While

    For index As Integer = 0 To PdfDocument.PageCount Step 1
        PdfDocument.PageNumber = index
        PdfDocument.Flatten()
    Next

    If PdfDocument.PageCount > 1 Then
        PdfDocument.PageNumber = 1
    End If
```

Same code is working fine on local machine and also on different environment but not working when i deploy it on live as well on some machines also. i have tried all the permission related fixes but not working in my case.

Can any body help me in this ??

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue and for me it worked adding the next line:

```
Dim PdfDocument As New WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc()
Dim PdfId As Integer

PdfDocument.HtmlOptions.Engine=WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.EngineType.Gecko //add this line
PdfDocument.Page = PdfDocument.AddPage()

[...]
```

Comment: Forgot to say, the look of your pdf might change slightly but depends if you prefer a different look for your pdf or not having it working at all!

Comment: Do we have this option in ABCPDF V6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because the older version of ABCpdf which you are using is not compatible with the environment on these newer machines.

Upgrading to the current release should be your first port of call.

For details of supported systems and features for different versions see:

http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-8.htm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where on some websites it worked and on some it didn't. These websites were on the same server!

I fixed it like this:
 - Open IIS Manager
 - Goto 'Application Pools'
 - Click on the Name of the application in question
 - Open the 'Advanced Settings'
 - Set 'Load user profile' to False
 - Restart the pool and the website

That did it for me, after more than an hour of searching.